# How to maintain background color of radgridview cell from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

How can I apply the background color of radgridview cell programmatically?  I have found that the background color no longer exists when I scroll up or down.

**xaml.cs**

```
private void dgQueue_RowLoaded(object sender, RowLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow GrdRow = e.Row as GridViewRow;
    EVQueue objEV = e.Row.DataContext as EVQueue;
    TextBlock txtActivityDate = null;
    TextBlock txtSendDate = null;
    int activityDateIndex = 0;
    if (GrdRow != null)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < GrdRow.Cells.Count; index++)
        {
            if (GrdRow.Cells[index].Column.UniqueName.Equals("ActivityDate", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (objEV.ActivityDate != null)
                {                          
                    txtActivityDate = (TextBlock)e.Row.Cells[index].Content;
                    activityDateIndex = index;
                }
            }

            if (GrdRow.Cells[index].Column.UniqueName.Equals("SendDate", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (objEV.SendDate != null)
                {
                    txtSendDate = (TextBlock)e.Row.Cells[index].Content;
                }
            }
        }                
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtActivityDate.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSendDate.Text))
        {                
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(txtActivityDate.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > Convert.ToDateTime(txtSendDate.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[activityDateIndex].Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="dgQueue"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Height="580"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        FontSize="12"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        ShowColumnFooters="true"
                        ShowGroupPanel="False"
                        telerikControls:StyleManager.Theme="Summer"
                        UseLayoutRounding="True"
                        RowLoaded="dgQueue_RowLoaded"
                        AllowDrop="False" TabIndex="14" >
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="*" UniqueName="ActivityDate" Name="datacolActivityDate"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding ActivityDate}"                                         
                                    Header="Activity Date" />

        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="*" UniqueName="SendDate"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding SendDate}"
                                    Header="Send Date" />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: Please show your code where you apply the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before, the way that i got round it is I found there style that i wanted to use in the SDK and put the style in my application.

Then I went to the Template property and found the root grid and set the TemplateBinding to the root Grid.

The issue you may be facing though is different. It could be a one of virtualization. You may need to actually set the background every time it appears, not sure that this is good practice though.